# WordPress app backebd, offline

Tags: wordpress, cordova, offline, ionic-framework

I am building an app using worpress as the backend and ionic as the front end. I know there are a number of metods to store data offline, what is the most robust option?  I will  be deployning on ios and android and the data may contail larger files, i am leaning towards using the file api and saving .json files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the Storage guide in the Cordova docs? (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

The "best" approach depends on what you are storing. If you are storing text based content, then WebSQL is probably best for you. If you are storing data that is more abstract (last article viewed, number of times something has been read, etc) then LocalStorage may be better.

Finally - I tend to only use the file system for binary data, like images, video, etc.

Comment: Thankyou for the fast response. I have had issues with LocalStorage size in the past. Maybe a mixture of websql and file system storage? I gould use the websql for text data and reference the image... In the file system?

Comment: My general rule of thumb is - if the data is "infinite" (not really, but can grow as needed), then I use WebSQL. If the data is finite (set items) I use LocalStorage. I think what you describe seems fine, and yes, you can reference images in the file system.